# Use KeyProcessFunction on KeyBy

Tags: apache-flink

I have a snippet of code that looks like this:

```java
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, Integer>> datastream = otherDatastream
        .keyBy(event -> event.getField(1))
        .process(new SomeFunction());
```

My `someFunction` is a class that extends the `KeyedProcessFunction`. But trying this code results in a `Cannot resolve method process(SomeFunction)`. I am unsure what the correct syntax would look like for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary to get all of the details in `SomeFunction` exactly right: the type parameters, method overrides, etc. If you share all of the details we can be more helpful, but a good strategy, in general, is to rely on your IDE to generate the boilerplate for you.

For starters, make sure that the `SomeFunction` class extends `KeyedProcessFunction<KEY, IN, OUT>`, where KEY is whatever type is returned by `event.getField(1)`, IN is whatever type `event` is, and OUT appears to be `Tuple2<Long, Integer>`.

Another strategy would be to start from working examples, like the ones in the [Apache Flink training repository](https://github.com/apache/flink-training).

Comment: If event is `Tuple<Long, Long, Long>`, then type signature should be `KeyedProcessFunction<Long, Tuple3<Long, Long, Long>, Tuple2<Long, Integer>>`?

Comment: If getField(1) returns a Long, then yes.